# Setting FTP Access is still allowing access to complete Server

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, ftp

I Tried Following to set the FTP access to a Users,

```
useradd user1

paaswd user1
```

Home directory set to   `sudo usermod -d /var/www/site-directory.com -m user1`

Block shell access for user `usermod -s /sbin/nologin user1`

folder permission `chown -R user1:www-data site-directory.com`

I'm not sure if I'm missing anything here. Kindly Guide me to any more settings to be checked to make it Secure to specific user

Comment: FTP is generally considered *insecure*; for more security used SSH/SFTP. https://linuxhint.com/setup-sftp-server-ubuntu/

Comment: i want provide folder access to a third party